# IOS 7: Tabbar Item Icons selected images not appearing right

Tags: xcode, ios7

I am developing an app in IOS 7 and I am setting the custom images for tabbar icons. Here is my code:

```
UIImage *musicImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"monitor"];
        UIImage *musicImageSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11"];

        musicImage = [musicImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        musicImageSel = [musicImageSel imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notifications" image:musicImage selectedImage:musicImageSel];
```

My problem is that when I select any tab in the tabbar the image just appears to enlarge.

I am attaching screen shot for more clarification. I just want the image to be in the tabbar. And also both the images are of 50X50px in size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try manipulating imageInset property. For me `(5,0,-5,0)` were ok - but I didn't use titleLabel

> self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notifications"
>   image:musicImage selectedImage:musicImageSel];
>
> self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5,0);